# I changed my Gmail primary account user name to my Yahoo e-mail and nothing works

Tags: gmail

When I was asked about a recovery e-mail address for my Gmail account I added my Yahoo account home e-mail address. This has become my primary (user name for my Gmail account and has locked up Google on my new phone, and my Gmail account....can't open to get in and fix anything.  Afraid to delete old account since it is attached to my new phone.

Comment: _I added my yahoo account home e-mail address. This has become my primary_ I don't think its possible. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Please see [How do I recover my Google username or password](/questions/52706/how-do-i-recover-my-google-password-or-username)

Answer (score 1):

The way to change the primary email address of a Google account is by canceling the Gmail address this will remove Gmail from the account and also could affect any other service that use a Gmail address as the user ID. But you could still get back your Gmail address.

From the reference

> **I want to get my deleted Gmail account back**
>   If you deleted your Gmail account but want it back, we work to help you recover your
>   deleted account whenever we can. Within a few weeks' time, the
>   account’s data might not be available anymore. You can find
>   instructions [for recovering your Gmail
>   username](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/67422) here.

**References**

- [Canceling your Gmail address - Google Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61177?hl=en)